# How can we create a tag with an icon?

Tags: support, tags

There is a new technology called **[UNO Platform](https://platform.uno/)** and I think that it would be good to have a *tag* and *icon* on stackoverflow.com and pt.stackoverflow.com:

`UNO-Platform`

[image: UNO Platform]

How can we do that?

Comment: "Uno", like "Unity", is an overloaded term. It is currently [occupied by the OpenOffice](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/uno/info).